# c++ shift array elements to left

Tags: c++, arrays, shuffle, shift

I've only recently taken up C++ and am having difficulty shifting array elements to remove empty/null elements

```
char *aBlock;
aBlock = new char[100];

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
aBlock[20] = 'a'; // fill array with test data.
aBlock[10] = 's';
aBlock[30] = 'd'; // Excepted output: This test data should be shifted to the start of array

// Consider aBlock contains data, with random empty elements
    for(int i=1; i <= aBlock.length(); i++) {
        if(aBlock[i-1] == 0) {
            aBlock[i-1] = aBlock[i];
            aBlock[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Edit:
Fixed a code typo & wrong variable names, changed "==" to "=".
It still doesn't work as expected.

Comment: A note about terminology: an array cannot have "empty" elements. In your case, you seem to want to remove elements with value `== 0`.

Comment: What is `.length()` of a pointer in the first place?

Comment: @juanchopanza Given the above code, I would call aBlock[50] empty as nothing has been assigned to it. What would be the correct terminology to describe its state?

Comment: "Full". Even if nothing had been assigned, there are values in each array position. If you want to count how many values are assigned, you´ll need a separate count variable

Comment: It has a value that is `== 0`, that's all. There is a `char` there, so it is not "empty", and `0` is a valid value for a `char` (usually the literal `\0` is used.)

Comment: Also an important note: your array is zero-initialized because it is global. But if it were defined inside of `main` or any other function, it would not be, so you would need to define it like this: `aBlock = new char[100]();`.

Comment: Have you ever tried compiling your code? This doesn't work at all. A pointer in C++ doesn't have a `length()` member and the variable `memBlock` is never declared.

Comment: How do you expect code that can't compile to "work"?

Comment: I *think* what he's trying to do is compacting the array, though he is quite a long ways off from working code, indeed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to move the non-zero elements at the beginning of your array. You could use `std::remove_if` to do this and set the rest of the elements to 0.

```
std::fill(
   std::remove_if(std::begin(aBlock), std::end(aBlock), [](char const c) {return c == '\0'; }),
   std::end(aBlock),
   0);
```

UPDATE:

Since the array is dynamically allocated you need a small change:

```
std::fill(
   std::remove_if(&aBlock[0], &aBlock[100], [](char const c) {return c == '\0'; }),
   &aBlock[100],
   0);
```

Comment: Nice idea, bit in this case `std::end` won't work because the array is dynamically allocated. Also, it would be simpler to use `std::remove` in this case.

Comment: Sure it would, just not with `begin` and `end`. But you could use `&aBlock[0]` and `&aBlock[100]`.

Comment: No Idea what you meant, but at least now it would work. I still don't see the reason to use `remove_if` over `remove`. It seems like an unnecessary complication.

Comment: Interesting idea. I gave it a try and get a compile error; `no matching function for call to ‘remove_if(char*, char*, MemManager::Compact()::__lambda0)’`

Comment: @AgentOrange Just use `std::remove(aBlock, aBlock + 100, '\0')`.

Comment: I'll accept this answer as it's creative and solves my problem. Though I did need to replace `remove_if` with `remove` as suggested by @juanchopanza Ty!

Answer (score 0):

change

```
    memBlock[i-1] == memBlock[i];
```

to

```
    memBlock[i-1] = memBlock[i];
```

"==" is the problem i think.

use

```
     if(aBlock[i-1] != 0)
```

Comment: While this might be an obvious error, this won't help very much. He tries to call `length()` on a `char*` for example. The code won't compile at all.

Answer (score 0):

Operator `==` checks the equality, you must use `=` to assign.

```
memBlock[i-1] = memBlock[i];
```

Arrays in C++ have not any member like `.length()`. They are not classes.

```
for(int i=1; i <= 100; i++)
                  ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the size at compile-time, use std::array if available. Then you can do ".size()" :) Also, your code doesn't work if you have several consecutive zeroes. Every element is shifted to the left at most once, which is clearly insufficient to achieve your desired result. What you need to do is keep track of a separate "output" index/iterator which receives any non-zero value you encounter and is then incremented:

```
std::array<char, 100> aBlock;
aBlock[10] = 's';
aBlock[20] = 'a';
aBlock[30] = 'd';

auto output = aBlock.begin(); // or aBlock if you don't have std::array;
for (auto input = aBlock.begin(); input != aBlock.end(); ++input)
{
  if (*input != 0)
  {
    if (output != input)
    {
      *output = input;
      *input = 0;
    }
    ++output;
  }
}
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: I do not know the array size at compile-time, can I create std:array at runtime? This would make things easier.

Comment: No, but for that you typically use std::vector, which can be dynamically resized (vector.resize(100) will make it contain 100 zeroes). The rest of the code would stay identical.

Answer (score 0):

```
int arrsize = 100;

...

int i, j;
for(i = 0, j = 0; i < arrsize ; i++) {
    if(memBlock[i] != 0 && i != j) {
        memBlock[j++] = memBlock[i];
        memBlock[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Side note: new in global space? And where is delete[] ?

Comment: Please a reason too. Maybe i´m too tired, but i can´t see a problem.

Comment: The fact that you're assigning memBlock[i] = 0 if you just tested for that should raise an alarm.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to test if you set a static array so you know what the result should look like.

Instead of playing with the original array.  I opted to create new one using .push_back(), then manipulating the new array.  Member function; .erase, is finicky and doesn't seem to like changing the original vector array.

IMO this is kind of jank lol, this is isn't what I was expecting the end resulting code to look like, but it does work.  I had imagined just replacing or swapping numbers each iteration but I couldn't get it work...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>



int main()
{
    std::vector<int> array1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::vector<int> array2;

    //each integer above 0 will "shift" the array1 to the left by one, so if you enter '0' or '5' it will either not move or move so it's back to the same order it started in
    int howmany;
    std::cout << "Shift left how many times?: ";
    std::cin >> howmany;

    //first part that always iterates will place all contents of array1 into array2
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.size(); i++) {
            array2.push_back(array1[i]);

            //if statement enacts when the loop completes, if (-1) is not added to the end of size it will not trigger
            if (i == array1.size() - 1) {
                //erases from the beginning of array1 to X which is set by (+ howmany) a variable controlled by the user, will shift left X times
                array2.erase(array2.begin(), array2.begin() + howmany);
                
                //again, using the howmany variable, add to the end what was erased from the beginning, starting at array1[0]
                for (int i = 0; i < howmany; i++) {
                    array2.push_back(array1[i]);
                }    
            }
    }

    //output for loop for the newly created array2 from contents of array
    for (int i = 0; i < array2.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << array2[i] << std::endl;
    }

}
```